# Croutons not showing properly - CroutonQueue somehow stuck?

Tags: android, notifications, crouton

I'm facing a serious problem with the Croutons Notification Library,
**When i quickly switch my activites**, sometimes (very often indeed) **croutons** for updates, like missing credentials, or "insert date first" **are not shown anymore**,
and so the users stay without any info, what's the problem.

For instance also the simple usecase:
Login To Application,
Logout,

try to re-login but with false credentials,
doesnt show a crouton anymore.

**I tried:**
`Courton.clearAllNotifcations()` in inPause(),
and additionally,
`Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(this)` too in **onPause()**,

to maybe solve the Problem, but it didn't.

I also **debugged** in the **CroutonLibrary** and the problem seems to be,
a Crouton gets added to queue, the the activity gets finished, the something finishes (like aSyncTask showing a crouton in onPostExecute(), this one gets added to the queue again, and then the **queue is stuck.**

Also.clearAllNotifications (which actually clears the queue) doesn't work, because the courton (asynctask finishes after acitvity.finish()) gets added afterwards, and the problem persists.

also tried:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
         Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(this);
         Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
         super.onDestroy();
     }
```

knwon issue: https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/24
but didn't work too...

**Thankful for any advice!**
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thx @keyboardsurfer** for the explanation...

**adding...**
and **extracting the AsyncTask** to a member variable...

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(this);
        if (loadTasksTask != null) {
            loadTasksTask.cancel(true);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**fixed the issue! :)
thx a lot :)**

Answer (score 1):

You have found the correct issue on Crouton and the part of the code that is responsible for producing the issue.

In your case it correlates with the `AsyncTask` which is still running when your `Activity` actually should have been destroyed already. It's generally a good thing to move long running behavior out of user facing components, i.e. using a service layer.

Until then [canceling the `AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) should do the trick.